# Understanding DHCP setting for DNS Server Options and Scope Options

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I have installed 2 DC's on my network (W2K8 R2) both serve as a replicate DC on my domain.

On one of them (DC1) there is also a DHCP server running.

On both I have a DNS server running.

I am trying to understand the difference in the settings within the DHCP of Server Options and Scope Options.

[image]

As I understand it: On the **server options**, I should put an external DNS for system (lets say 8.8.8.8 - google)
And on the **scope options**, I should put both my internal dc1 and dc2 IP's as the server. - which are than distributed to my domain clients.

Is that correct?

Is there a better way?

Do I need to add loopback address as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The server options apply to every scope on the server; the scope options override the server settings for that specific scope.

Because you have only one scope on this server, it really doesn't matter which settings you put where right now.  However, if you plan to have another network (such as a guest network without access to your domain, or a new internal network with another domain) served by this DHCP server, you should set all the settings in the scopes.  You could leave a set of failsafe defaults in the server settings if you wanted.

It is not necessary to configure anything to do with the loopback address in DHCP.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. My DNS server should have it's DNS from the provider. I don't want all my domain to have the same, they should use the Internal DNS as their DNS. How do I control that?

Comment: All your servers should have DNS from the domain, because AD requires this to work.  Your DNS servers can be configured to use your ISP's dns as a forwarder, though (this is done in the DNS configuration; your DNS servers should be using localhost as a resolver in their network config).  The result of this is that all queries about your domain will be answered by your servers, and all outside queries will be answered by the ISP.